# What does "peer country" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Does it mean "the country which offers help"?

However, "these qualifiers should not obscure the core insight," he wrote. "A large and growing number of countries could quickly take the lead in ending their own extreme income poverty. A mix of domestic and **peer country** pressure is needed to focus efforts."

Source: http://www.businessinsider.com/cash-transfer-recipients-on-free-money-2016-11/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This article plays on the term "peer pressure" which is used in human to human situations. By adding the word "country" to create "peer country pressure", the meaning is applied to a country to country situation.

Peer Preassure: a feeling that one must do the same things as other people of one's age and social group in order to be liked or respected by them.  *"She started drinking in high school because of peer pressure."* - [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/peer%20pressure)